# data syncing with server to room database

Tags: android, offline, android-room

I am new to android. In my android app, I showing the products list. Now I can sync all the products with a single API call. In slow networks, the app getting broken with the timeout error. I want to sync the products by chunks of data and I want to show a loader also. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something called `Pagination`. You can get a specific list/chunk of products from your API with a specified 'page' parameter. The 'page' parameter usually starts off with a value of 0 `(page=0)`, then when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list, you increment the 'page' parameter and get the next chunk of data `(page=1)`, So on as the user scrolls to the bottom of the list.

To show a lading to let the user know of data being loaded from the API, simply use a progress bar that can be shown whenever the API call is in progress and hidden when the API call is finished.